# Nested Json deserialize c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a json string like this;

```
[
  {
    "ID": 123456789,
    "userInf": {
      "Name": "NameSurname1",
      "Adress": "example adress"
    },
    "price": "3898.30",
    "kdv": "701.69",
    "total": "4599,99",
    "note": "example note"
  },
  {
    "ID": 98756431,
    "userInf": {
      "Name": "NameSurname2",
      "Adress": "example address2"
    },
    "price": "1116.10",
    "kdv": "82.90",
    "total": "1199.00",
    "note": "example note2"
  }
]
```

And build up classes like this;

```
public partial class Sale
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public UserInf UserInf { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Kdv { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserInf
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
}
```

And I call json with this code and deserialize;

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sale>(jsonstring);
var shapedData = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(x =>
                    new
                    {
                        ID = data.ID,
                        userInf = data.UserInf.Name,
                        price = data.Price,
                        kdv = data.Kdv,
                        total = data.Total,
                        note= data.Note
                    }).ToList();

DataTable dt = ToDataTable(shapedData);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

and I get error. But if I change my json and cut the second half and delete the [,] symbols code just works perfectly fine. I need to deserialize multiple like above and tried multiple ways to deserialize but this is the closest way I get so far.

I get the error on this line ;

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sale>(jsonstring);
```

Error is

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type .. and so.

I know I'm missing something very basic but I have no coder friend to ask.
I would be grateful if you could suggest a better way to do it.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you want to deserialize an array of objects into a single object. Use a collection for deserialization like ICollection<Sale> or ensure the json contains no array

Comment: BTW you do have a coder friend: google for *json.net Cannot deserialize the current JSON array*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should deserialize it as collection;

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sale>>(jsonstring);
```

And your linq query looks like;

```
var shapedData = data.Select(x =>
    new
    {
       ID = x.ID,
       userInf = x.UserInf.Name,
       price = x.Price,
       kdv = x.Kdv,
       total = x.Total,
       note = x.note
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: yes i think it will work but how I'm going to use
 ID = data.ID,
 userInf = data.UserInf.Name,

Answer (score 1):

can you try like this , dont make use of var as you already know return type

```
List<Sale> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sale>>(jsonstring);
```

as your string return array of data